# How Should I Design like SplitviewController in React Native?

Tags: ios, react-native, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller, master-detail

I'm Developing an Application on iPad in react native, in which I have to design Screen like UISplitViewController / Master-Detail View. Is there any way to achieve this kind of design. I'm using react-native-router-flux for navigation.